GitHub Actions publish to PyPI: ModuleNotFoundError for requirement that's in setup.py
I have an Action that publishes a library to PyPI. I've used the exact same configuration (setup.py, python-publish.yml, etc.) for different libraries before, but I've never seen this before.
It's set so that whenever I publish a Release, it publishes the new version to PyPI. Again, it's worked for more than one library before.
Here's the log: https://github.com/silvncr/osutool/actions/runs/9156911705/job/25172226841
Extract:
File "/home/runner/work/osutool/osutool/osutool/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from colorama import init as colorama_init
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

setup.py includes this line in the setup() call:
install_requires=['colorama==0.4.6'],

Here's the Action file, if you need it:
name: publish
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
permissions:
  contents: read
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.x'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install build
    - name: Build package
      run: python -m build
    - name: Publish package
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@27b31702a0e7fc50959f5ad993c78deac1bdfc29
      with:
        user: __token__
        password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_API_TOKEN }}


Answer:
I fixed the problem with the help of @ken-morel. I still don't know why this happened in the first place, but at least it's published now.
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install --upgrade build colorama pytest_runner setuptools wheel
    - name: Build package
      run: python -m build -n


That is due to build creating an isolated environment in which it does not install your dependencies.
I do not know how to specify dependencies,
but there is a turnaround.
Use the -n option to get the feature removed.
And manually install all your dependencies, adding setuptools, wheel and pytest_runner.
